# Custom syntax for workspace in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a custom syntax (json varietas) for a specific project.
I've created a project that contains the `t-json.tmLanguage.json` and `language-configuration.json`, but I won't publish it as an extension because it's not general used.

So can I configure something in `.vscode/` folder for support the syntax **only for this workspace**?

Comment: I'm pretty sure grammars can only be contributed via extensions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode support a custom json syntax with multiline string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748939/vscode-support-a-custom-json-syntax-with-multiline-string-literal)